# how to join 2 query into one in EXCEL ORACLE CONNECTION

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, odbc, ms-query

I have 2 query. 
I am trying to join them so I just write export from one instead of manually joining them in excel.

```
(SELECT 
        b.OUT_NO, 
        a.ACCNO, 
        a.BILL_ACCNO, 
        a.NAME, 
        a.HOUSE_NO, 
        a.STREET, 
        a.HOUSE_NO2, 
        a.ZIP, 
        a.ID, 
        b.TIME_STAMP, 
        b.REST_DATE, 
        c.RESTORED_TIME, 
        b.OUT_CMNT
   FROM brook.account a, 
        brook.problem b, 
        brook.history c
  WHERE c.OUT_NO = b.OUT_NO 
    AND a.ID = c.ID 
    AND (  (a.NAME Is Not Null) 
       AND (a.DISC Is Null) 
       AND (b.TIME_STAMP>?) 
       AND (c.RESTORED_TIME<?))
)
```

and

```
(SELECT 
       b.OUT_NO, 
       a.ACCNO, 
       a.BILL_ACCNO, 
       a.NAME, 
       a.HOUSE_NO, 
       a.STREET, 
       a.HOUSE_NO2, 
       a.ZIP, 
       a.ID, 
       b.TIME_STAMP, 
       b.REST_DATE, 
       c.RESTORED_TIME, 
       b.OUT_CMNT
  FROM brook.account a, 
       brook.problem b, 
       brook.history c
 WHERE c.OUTAGE_NO = b.OUTAGE_NO 
   AND a.ID = c.ID 
   AND (   (a.NAME Is Not Null) 
       AND (a.DISC Is Null) 
       AND (b.TIME_STAMP > ? And b.TIME_STAMP < ?) 
       AND (c.RESTORED_TIME > ? And c.RESTORED_TIME < ?)
       )
)
```

How can I join these 2? into 1, I tried `UNION ALL` but I get `ora-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`  ERROR.

`?` are the parameter, it is linked to cells on spreadsheet. 
format of excel data parameter. `11/04/2013 00:00:00`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error is about a date format, not about union.
If you pass cell values as string parameters Oracle tries to convert it to dates to comapre with columns of `date` or `timestamp` values in table columns. To do this conversion Oracle uses it's internal default [date representation format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) wich is not `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` in your case.

There are 2 possibilities to fix a situation:

1. Pass parameters with `date` type to query and convert values to dates before passing it to Oracle.  Check [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and description of [CreateParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Parameters.Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods.
2. Convert values to dates in query with [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm#i1003589) Oracle function.

Change conditions in query from

```
   AND (b.TIME_STAMP>?) 
   AND (c.RESTORED_TIME<?))
```

and

```
   AND (b.TIME_STAMP > ? And b.TIME_STAMP < ?) 
   AND (c.RESTORED_TIME > ? And c.RESTORED_TIME < ?)
```

to

```
   AND (b.TIME_STAMP > to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) 
   AND (c.RESTORED_TIME < to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ))
```

and

```
   AND (
        b.TIME_STAMP > to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
        And 
        b.TIME_STAMP < to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
       ) 
   AND (
        c.RESTORED_TIME > to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
        And 
        c.RESTORED_TIME < to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
       )
```